# How to get ListViewItem using his FlyoutMenuItem?

Tags: listview, uwp, listviewitem, flyout

XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <MenuFlyout x:Key = "ElementMenuFlyout">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text = "Edit" Icon = "Edit" Click = "Edit"/>
    </MenuFlyout>
</Page.Resources>

...
<ListView SelectionMode = "None" IsItemClickEnabled = "True" x:Name="Lessons"></ListView>
```

Initialization of ListView.Items:

```
foreach (Tables.Lesson lesson in lessons)
{
    Lessons.Items.Add(new ListViewItem {Content = lesson, ContextFlyout = this.Resources["ElementMenuFlyout"] as MenuFlyout });
}
```

MenuFlyoutItem.Click:

```
private void Edit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(ElementInfo), (e.OriginalSource as MenuFlyoutItem).DataContext);
}
```

I get null in DataContext. How to get ListViewItem that have called this MenuFlyout or Content of this ListViewItem?

Answer (score 0):

> How to get ListViewItem that have called this MenuFlyout or Content of this ListViewItem?

When you tried to trigger the `MenuFlyout` which is belong to the `ContextFlyout` of `ListView`, you may need to right click the `ListView` on the PC or long tap it on the mobile, both will trigger the [`RightTapped`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_RightTapped)
 event handle firstly. By `RightTappedRoutedEventArgs` you can get the current right tapped [`ListViewItemPresenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.listviewitempresenter) then can get the `DataContext`. For example:

XAML

```
<ListView
    x:Name="Lessons"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    RightTapped="Lessons_RightTapped"
    SelectionMode="None" />
```

Code behind

```
private ListViewItemPresenter currentitem; 
private void Edit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    if (currentitem != null)
    {  
       Frame.Navigate(typeof(ElementInfo), currentitem.DataContext);
    }  
} 
private void Lessons_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    currentitem = e.OriginalSource as ListViewItemPresenter;
}
```